# Magento 2 - remove everything after hr tag

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.3, attributes

I have one attribute with the name ***tech_data*** and in this attribute I have the following values:

```
<p><a title="SDS" href="PDF/SDS/SDS.pdf" target="_blank">SDS</a> | <a title="Sheet" href="PDF/Specification/Sheet.pdf" target="_blank">Sheet</a> | <a class="caption" title="Brochure" href="/downloads/brochures/performance" target="_blank">Brochure</a> <hr />
<p> </p>
<p>Insulation Type: Insulator - Designed to be put directly on heat source to keep in</p>
```

I use the following code to split them in a separated ***li tag***, I replace **|** with the ***li tag***.

How I can remove everything after ***hr tag***?

This is what I try:

```
<?php $attr = explode("|",$this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block, $block->getProduct()->getTechData(), 'tech_data')); 
    if(isset($attr)) {
?>

    <ul class="custom-attribute">
        <?php foreach ($attr as $attrValue) { 
        ?>
            <li class="button"><?php echo $attrValue; ?></li>
 <?php
        } 
?>
    </ul>
 <?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Explode should do the trick here:

```
$value = explode("<hr />", $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block, $block->getProduct()->getTechData(), 'tech_data'));
$value = reset($value);
$attr = explode("|",$value);
```

The `explode` splits the string into a number of array items (depending on the number of HRs). The `reset` returns the first item in the array.

Comment: thank you, but how I can use the two functions on the same attribute? I mean I need to keep my first function to replace | with li tag too and to remove everything after hr on the same attribute?

Comment: @Robert I've updated my answer to reflext this

Comment: I have this error:

Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string on this line: $value = reset(explode("<hr />",$attr));

Comment: @Robert ok this one should be right :)

Comment: now I have this "Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in" on this line:

$value = reset(explode("<hr />", $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block, $block->getProduct()->getTechData(), 'tech_data')));

Comment: try and pass the results of the explode in a variable first, then put it in the reset, that should help

Comment: can you edit your answer please, I try something but is not work, I have the same error.

Comment: Sure, it's updated

Comment: It's perfect now, thank you very much, I really appreciate your help ...

Comment: Sure, happy to help :)